# AVAssetWriter continuous segments

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I want to record a series of clips that when played together via a video player or `ffmpeg -f concat` play back seemlessly.

In either scenario right now, I'm getting a very noticeable audio hiccup at each segment join point.

My current strategy is to maintain 2 `AssetWriter` instances. At each cut off point, I start up a new writer, wait until it's ready, then start giving it samples. When video and audio samples are done at a specific point in time, I close the the last writer.

How do I modify this to get continuous clip recording? What's the root cause issue?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class StreamController: UIViewController, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

    var closingVideoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var closingAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var closingAssetWriter: AVAssetWriter?

    var currentVideoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var currentAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var currentAssetWriter: AVAssetWriter?

    var nextVideoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var nextAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var nextAssetWriter: AVAssetWriter?

    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var videoHelper: VideoHelper?

    var startTime: NSTimeInterval = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        createSegmentWriter()
        videoHelper = VideoHelper()
        videoHelper!.delegate = self
        videoHelper!.startSession()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "createSegmentWriter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func createSegmentWriter() {
        print("Creating segment writer at t=\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - self.startTime)")
        nextAssetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: OutputFileNameHelper.instance.pathForOutput()), fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4)
        nextAssetWriter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        let videoSettings: [String:AnyObject] = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey: 960, AVVideoHeightKey: 540]
        nextVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
        nextVideoInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        nextAssetWriter?.addInput(nextVideoInput!)

        let audioSettings: [String:AnyObject] = [
                AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        ]
        nextAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
        nextAudioInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        nextAssetWriter?.addInput(nextAudioInput!)

        nextAssetWriter!.startWriting()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: videoHelper!.captureSession)
        previewLayer!.frame = self.previewView.bounds
        previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        if ((previewLayer?.connection?.supportsVideoOrientation) != nil) {
            previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
        }
        self.previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    }

    func closeWriter() {
        if videoFinished && audioFinished {
            let outputFile = closingAssetWriter?.outputURL.pathComponents?.last
            closingAssetWriter?.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler() {
                let delta = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - self.startTime
                print("segment \(outputFile) finished at t=\(delta)")
            }
            self.closingAudioInput = nil
            self.closingVideoInput = nil
            self.closingAssetWriter = nil
            audioFinished = false
            videoFinished = false
        }
    }

    func closingVideoFinished() {
        if closingVideoInput != nil {
            videoFinished = true
            closeWriter()
        }
    }

    func closingAudioFinished() {
        if closingAudioInput != nil {
            audioFinished = true
            closeWriter()
        }
    }

    var closingTime: CMTime = kCMTimeZero
    var audioFinished = false
    var videoFinished = false
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        let sampleTime: CMTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
        if let nextWriter = nextAssetWriter {
            if nextWriter.status.rawValue != 0 {
                print("Switching asset writers at t=\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - self.startTime)")

                closingAssetWriter = currentAssetWriter
                closingVideoInput = currentVideoInput
                closingAudioInput = currentAudioInput

                currentAssetWriter = nextAssetWriter
                currentVideoInput = nextVideoInput
                currentAudioInput = nextAudioInput

                nextAssetWriter = nil
                nextVideoInput = nil
                nextAudioInput = nil

                closingTime = sampleTime
                currentAssetWriter!.startSessionAtSourceTime(sampleTime)
            }
        }

        if currentAssetWriter != nil {
            if let _ = captureOutput as? AVCaptureVideoDataOutput {
                if (CMTimeCompare(sampleTime, closingTime) < 0) {
                    if closingVideoInput?.readyForMoreMediaData == true {
                        closingVideoInput?.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                    }
                } else {
                    closingVideoFinished()
                    if currentVideoInput?.readyForMoreMediaData == true {
                        currentVideoInput?.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                    }
                }

            } else if let _ = captureOutput as? AVCaptureAudioDataOutput {
                if (CMTimeCompare(sampleTime, closingTime) < 0) {
                    if currentAudioInput?.readyForMoreMediaData == true {
                        currentAudioInput?.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                    }
                } else {
                    closingAudioFinished()
                    if currentAudioInput?.readyForMoreMediaData == true {
                        currentAudioInput?.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight]
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update on how you ended up on this?

Comment: i'am trying to solve a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322157/split-cmsamplebufferref-containing-audio

Answer (score 1):

I think that the root cause is due to the video and audio `CMSampleBuffer`s representing different time intervals. You need to split and join the audio `CMSampleBuffer`s to make them slot seamlessly into your `AVAssetWriter`'s timeline, which should probably be based on the video presentation timestamps.

Why should audio have to change and not video? It seems asymmetric, but I guess it's because audio has the higher sampling rate.

p.s. actually creating the new split sample buffers looks intimidating. `CMSampleBufferCreate` has a tonne of arguments. `CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange` might be easier and more efficient to use.

Comment: Might it be possible to use CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange to cut the piece of the sample I need on one side, and also get the remainder for the next AVAssetWriter? 

I wonder if a given sample itself may jump the time border, but properly partitioning samples may be enough.

It appears that a sample buffer will usually (always?) contain a single frame of video, but audio gets many samples, hence the asymmetry.

Comment: `CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange` looks promising and video is always 1 frame. You're right, there's no reason why a sample _should_ fall on frame boundaries. But maybe AVFoundation will cut for you - an overhanging audio buffer might "just" work if you append it in both current & next writers. Or maybe you should split your files at audio buffer boundaries or audio sample boundaries, repeating/cutting video frames as necessary. This would give you constant file durations thanks to audio's constant sampling rate.

Comment: splitting at an audio boundary is probably simpler. I'll try that. Constant file segment length is actually required +- seconds, but it'll be a nice feature to have regardless.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something interesting. The file chunks remind me of an instant replay app I was working on a long time ago.  The hardware wasn't quite up to simultaneous encoding/decoding at the time. Probably a different story now.

Comment: Any luck on the splitting buffers? i'am facing a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322157/split-cmsamplebufferref-containing-audio

Comment: You can create two new buffers with `CMSampleBufferCreate`