# Split CMSampleBufferRef containing Audio

Tags: cocoa-touch, avfoundation, core-audio, cmsamplebufferref, cmsamplebuffer

I'am splitting the recording into different files while recording...

The problem is, captureOutput video and audio sample buffers doesn't correspond 1:1 (which is logical)

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection

AUDIO START: 36796.833236847        | DURATION: 0.02321995464852608         | END: 36796.856456802
VIDEO START: 36796.842089239        | DURATION: nan         | END: nan
AUDIO START: 36796.856456805        | DURATION: 0.02321995464852608         | END: 36796.87967676
AUDIO START: 36796.879676764        | DURATION: 0.02321995464852608         | END: 36796.902896719
VIDEO START: 36796.875447239        | DURATION: nan         | END: nan
...
```

**so i need to split the audio `CMSampleBufferRef` based on time and use the first segment for the first video and the second part of the buffer for the second video**

It is possible to do things also with `AVMutableComposition` and `AVAssetExportSession` while exporting but the question is about the buffer level in `captureOutput:`, so the recorder file doesn't need more processing

---

**Update:**

Looks like 3 options, not successfully implemented yet

1) **`CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange`**

looks like `CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange` is the way to go, but i'am struggling to compute the last argument `sampleRange`...

2) **`CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming`**

quite lost using this one

3) looks like there is a way to trim the buffer by providing `kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_TrimDurationAtStart, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_TrimDurationAtEnd` using the `CMSetAttachment`

Comment: Were you able to fix that? what was the solution?

Comment: nope, sorry, didnt figured this out :(

Comment: did wen with a different approach a recorded the video and audio separatly

Comment: `CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange` is the way to go, but only if you have interleaved (or mono) audio. If you have non interleaved, it's a `CMBlockBufferCreateEmpty()` for each piece, with `CMBlockBufferAppendBufferReference()` + `CMAudioSampleBufferCreateWithPacketDescriptions()` for each channel.